# bash - how to remove first 2 lines from output

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following output in a text file:

```
106 pages in list
.bookmarks
20130516 - Daily Meeting Minutes
20130517 - Daily Meeting Minutes
20130520 - Daily Meeting Minutes
20130521 - Daily Meeting Minutes
```

I'm looking to remove the first 2 lines from my output. This particular shell script that I use to execute, always has those first 2 lines.

This is how I generated and read the file:

```
#Lists
PGLIST="$STAGE/pglist.lst";
RUNSCRIPT="$STAGE/runPagesToMove.sh";

#Get List of pages
$ATL_BASE/confluence.sh $CMD_PGLIST $CMD_SPACE "$1" > "$PGLIST";

# BUILD executeable script
echo "#!/bin/bash" >> $RUNSCRIPT 2>&1
IFS=''
while read line
  do
     echo "$ATL_BASE/conflunce.sh $CMD_MVPAGE $CMD_SPACE "$1" --title \"$line\" --newSpace \"$2\" --parent \"$3\"" >> $RUNSCRIPT 2>&1
done < $PGLIST
```

How do I remove those top 2 lines?

Comment: Those lines look like they're generated in your other scripts. Try looking for `echo` statements in your other files such as `runPagesToMove.sh` and `confluence.sh`. If you post those files, someone might be able to resolve the issue, but the problem isn't really resolvable from the code given.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The classic answer would use `sed` to delete lines 1 and 2:

```
sed 1,2d "$PGLIST"
```

Comment: i had this working last night - `./runscript.sh > "$PGLIST" | sed 1,2d $PGLIST` but for some reason, its not working now. So, I tried it this way too, but no luck.  `./runscript.sh > "$PGLIST" | sed 1,2d $PGLIST > $PGLIST;`

Comment: You didn't have what you show 'working' last night.  Last night, you either omitted the `>` or you had a semi-colon (or newline) in place of the `|`.  Be wary of trying to read and write a single file in a pipeline; you usually end up clobbering the file before it is read, which leads to exasperation.  On the whole, I think what you're looking for is `./runscript.sh | sed 1,2d > "$PGLIST"`, but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 42):

You can achieve this with `tail`:

```
tail -n +3 "$PGLIST"
```

> ```
>   -n, --lines=K
>           output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K
>           to output starting with the Kth
> ```

Comment: Wow, even works on macOS!  macOs makes no mention of this in its `man` page.

Answer (score 9):

awk way:

```
awk 'NR>2' "$PGLIST"
```